# Setting default page to a path IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

How do I set the default document to a subdirectory page? i.e. instead of default.htm something like /myWebApp/newDefault.htm?

The page I want is in a directory in wwwroot

Many thanks

Comment: Try this: it seems the same issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/68497/how-do-you-configure-iis-7-to-use-a-subdirectory-as-the-default-document

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at URL Rewriting?

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Or if you are using ASP.NET you could do something like this:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
context.Response.Redirect("myWebApp/newDefault.htm", true);
}
```

-M